# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE Data too long for column exception

Tags: c#, mysql, bulkinsert

I'm using MySQL `LOAD DATA INFILE Data` command to bulk insert data to a table. Here's how I am doing it :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'MyFile.csv' INTO TABLE `dbname`.`tablename` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ;
```

When I run it from our C# project I'm getting a `Data too long for column xxx` exception for a char(50) column which the provided data for it is less than 50 (but it is in Persian)but when I use a MySql client such as SQLyog it is working fine.

Here's how I am running this command :

```
private static void RunCommand(string command,params object[] args)
        {
            if (args != null)
                command = string.Format(command, args);
            using (var conn = MySqlClientFactory.Instance.CreateConnection())
            {
                if (conn == null) return;
                conn.ConnectionString =
                    "Server=localhost;Uid=root;Pwd=123456; AutoEnlist=false;Charset=utf8;";
                conn.Open();
                using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    comm.CommandText = command;
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

I guess that it could be an issue of converting `Unicode` characters but I can not figure out how can I make it run correctly.

Comment: Try to add `CHARACTER SET utf8` parameter to `LOAD DATA INFILE...` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `CHARACTER SET utf8` parameter to `LOAD DATA INFILE...` statement:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'MyFile.csv'
 INTO TABLE `dbname`.`tablename`
 CHARACTER SET utf8
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

As stated in [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) it specifies which character set is used in the file:

> The character set indicated by the character_set_database system
>   variable is used to interpret the information in the file. SET NAMES
>   and the setting of character_set_client do not affect interpretation
>   of input. If the contents of the input file use a character set that
>   differs from the default, it is usually preferable to specify the
>   character set of the file by using the CHARACTER SET clause, which is
>   available as of MySQL 5.1.17.

If it is not specified then gets default value, for example `latin1` and each `utf-8` byte is interpreted as character. Because some `utf-8` encoded characters has more than one byte you got longer strings.

Comment: Thank you :) it seems that I was in such a hurry that I miss the obvious.